# Regular Expression to extract a text with a variable length

Tags: regex, string, substring, text-extraction

I want to write a regex which will return the first occurrence of a pattern, which might have a variable length, for ex

```
1J-AB-AO08-F-15 ==> AB

1P-ABCD-AO08-F-15 ==> ABCD

1L-KK-KKK-F-1000 ==> KK

1M-L-AO08L-F-15 ==> L
```

I referred some online articles and examples but couldn't find a solution to match the above pattern, basically I want to extract the first occurrence of "-some text-" in a string where the text "might" be in variable length.

please help.

Comment: what language or tool?  regular expressions are not standardized so it makes a difference if you want the answer in python, bash, etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: this is for postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

This is one way: `^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})`

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('1J-AC-AO08-F-15', '^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})'));
SELECT (regexp_matches('1P-ABCD-AO08-F-15', '^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})'));
SELECT (regexp_matches('1L-KK-KKK-F-1000', '^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})'));
SELECT (regexp_matches('1L-BBM-KKK-F-1000', '^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})'));
SELECT (regexp_matches('1L-LL-KKK-F-1000', '^\w{1,}-(\w{1,})'));
```

Result:

```
AC
ABCD
KK
BBM
LL
```

If you know that the first portion of the string is fixed length (`1J-` you could use: `^\w{2}-(\w{1,})`